# Problem using ColorBox with Media Galllery

Tags: javascript

I want to create photo gallery using the [Media Gallery](https://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) module. One of the requirements given is to unpack the [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) jQuery plugin in `sites/all/libraries`.

I downloaded the file `colorbox-master.zip` and extracted it in `sites/all/libraries` so the path of colorbox is `sites/all/libraries/colorbox-master`

I am able to create gallery but effect of the ColorBox is not visible. What do I have to do to make the gallery photo show up in the ColorBox?

Answer (score 2):

Actually all you should need to do is change... Well, you'll need to change two things actually:

1. Rename `sites/all/library` to `sites/all/libraries`
2. Rename `colorbox-master` to `colorbox`

The final output should look like this: `sites/all/libraries/colorbox`

And don't forget to flush the caches after you make the changes, just to make sure the system recognizes them. ;)

Hope that helps... :)

Comment: ohh sorry, i was puting colorbox in sites/all/libraries only. 
and i have changed the name to `colorbox` and cleared chache too but still i am not seeing effect of colorbox

Comment: Did you enable the [colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) module? I would assume that's a requirement, but maybe not...?

Comment: no i didnt i guess colorbox module's features are already builtin in media_gallery